# Десериализация внешних файлов в Android приложении

Tags: android, файловая-система, сериализация, io

Допустим есть класс Foo.java, который я сериализовал в десктопном Java-приложении для того, чтобы использовать его в Android-приложении. В итоге получился файл testSerial.gbw, который я положил в директорию проекта Android-Studio рядом с пакетами моего приложения Android (см. скрин).

[image: Скрин из android studio]

так же я добавил шаблон класса Foo.java в проект Android-приложения для того, чтобы провести классическую (как мне казалось/хотелось) десериализацию:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

Foo foo = (Foo) ois.readObject();
```

В итоге я даже не подумал о том что это андроид а не джава, и после компиляции приложение уже запускается на устройстве, в котором а) другая файловая система б) приложение упаковано в app. Из б) так же следует вопрос, куда девается файл testSerial.gbw после упаковки проекта в app? как мне найти этот файл и подключить его в моем приложении? Грубо говоря, как и где найти мой testSerial.gbw в уже скомпилированном приложении, или куда его положить? или я изначально выбрал неправильный способ сериализации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Десериализации скорее всего будет работать нормально. А вот файлы к которым вы хотите получить доступ в рантайме на андройде надо класть в папку assets (если память не изменяет на одном уровне с папкой java). Прочесть положенный туда файл можно так:

```
context.getResources().getAssets().open("testSerial.gbw")
```

Comment: да, это работает. Уже и сам спрофитил, спасибо!

Comment: @player, если ответ правильный, отметьте его ,как правильный

Answer (score 1):

В Android Studio создаем директорию Assets:

**File -> New -> Folder -> Assets Folder**

Кладем в эту директорию нужны файл для десериализации, получается:

**assets/wastedtime.ser**

Теперь мы можем воспользоваться AssetManager для доступа к файлу:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream fis = am.open("wastedtime.ser"); //возвращает InputStream а не FileInputStream
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            wastedtime = (MyClass) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
            label.setText(wastedtime.getWastedTime());
```

Все работает, теперь конечно проблема с версиями классов, вываливается ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это, как говориться, совсем другая история.

Comment: проблема совместимости классов Java и Android тоже решилась. Важно жестко задавать static final long serialVersionUID, потому что десериализация очень чувствительна к компилятору, соответственно в стоковом варианте serialVersionUID никогда не совпадет с сериализованным в Java классе.